# Plotting Matlab figures in the background by default

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How can I plot Matlab figures in the background by default? I know that I can switch the visibility of individual figures as follows:

```
set(gcf, 'visible', 'off')
```

buy I'm looking for a way to set it as the default behaviour in the beginning of my script, just as I set the default line width with:

```
set(0,'defaultlinelinewidth', 1.5);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set(0,'DefaultFigureVisible','off')`

See [MathWorks documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/setting-default-property-values.html) to use this default mechanism on any parameter.